# Return hostname, but wait as it is no empty

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ip, sh, hostname

What am I doing is printing ip to file, but sometimes the file is empty. What I want to do, to run the command over and over untill it returns ip address. Now I am doing it like this:

```
sudo touch /etc/ip.txt && sudo chmod a+rwx /etc/ip.txt && sudo printf %s "$(hostname -I)" > /etc/ip.txt
```

The thing is that I am using this IP to fill it in other files, but when it's empty other scripts can't be executed. Any sugestions?

Comment: Why would `hostname` sometimes **not** return the IP address? And, since you give the file write permission to everyone, why do you use `sudo` for creating it then? And why do you give x-permission? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: Also, the `sudo` has no effect on the writing of _ip.txt_, because the redirection is set up by the shell **before** sudo is running.

Comment: Don't know why, but sometimes when all scripts execute I see that places where IP should be copied is empty and all scripts are crashing.

Comment: So, first I would fix this, before trying to do a non-sense retry. As a starting point, fix the logic in your command. Basically, you need the write to create something in `/etc`, and this is not covered by your code yet.

Comment: Thx for your comments, but this part is working now and I need a solution for the rest. Maybe later I would change it. Now it's not the topic of discusion.

Comment: My guess this **is** related. I don't believe that `hostname` sometimes does not return the requested output. I believe that sometimes `hostname` is not even invoked, because the shell can't set up the redirection. At least I would run the commands with `-x` turned on to see what's going on.

Comment: @Jbro - How is the _IP_ _copied_ by the _other scripts_?

Comment: @Armali It's like this: sudo sed -i 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' /etc/ip.txt)/g' /etc/_file-loader/startup.sh
It's mean to copy ip and replace current ip in file startup.sh

Comment: The command you show couldn't work, as the command substitution `$(sed …` is between single quotes. So, how is it really done, and what is the `s:/:\\/:g` supposed to achieve?